# R Evaluates "paste" as character rather than value

Tags: r

I have weights associated with variables:

```
WeightVar1 <- .75
WeightVar2 <- .8
WeightVar3 <- .10
```

I want to write a function that completes the following task:

```
Var1_New <- Var1 * WeightVar1
Var2_New <- Var2 * WeightVar2
Var3_New <- Var3 * WeightVar3
```

It would look something like this

```
for (i in 1:3)
{
Var_New <- paste("Var",i,sep="") * paste("WeightVar",i,sep="")
Var_New <- paste("Var",i,"_New",sep="")
}
```

The issue is R evaluating paste("WeightVar1",i,sep="") as "WeightVar1" rather than the numeric value, .75.

I am evaluating datasets with varying number of variables and weights, so rather than evaluating them individual, having a function that can iterate to the ith would save time and keep code clean.

Comment: `get(paste0("WeightVar", i))` ?

Comment: Try `Map('*', mget(paste0("Var", 1:3)), mget(paste0("WeightVar", 1:3)))`

Comment: `paste("WeightVar1",i,sep="")` *should* be `"WeightVar1"` since `i` is 1, not 0.75. Similarly, see the output of `paste("hello", "world")`, which has nothing to do with any variables present in your environment.

Comment: Thanks! @AdamQuek, the get() does exactly what I need it too! Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @r2evans yes, correct it would be WeightVar1, but I set the value of WeightVar1 <= .75 earlier in the code, so I wanted it to equal the value set to WeightVar1 rather than the text, "WeightVar1". As AdamQuek pointed out, the get() function accomplishes this.

Comment: someone should probably point out that this (get/eval) is generally considered bad practice in R. Most likely the problem can be reformulated in a different way that would have cleaner syntax, and less error-prone. (Typically, grouping things together in a named list and accessing elements by name with `[[`)

Answer (score 0):

I would do things rather differently. First, I'd create a data frame with columns for `Var` and `WeightVar`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var = c(10, 20, 30), 
                  WeightVar = c(0.75, 0.8, 0.1)
                 )
```

Then I'd write the function:

```
make_new_var <- function(var, weightvar) {
    var * weightvar
}
```

Then I'd pass the columns of the data frame to the function:

```
df1$NewVar <- make_new_var(df1$Var, df1$WeightVar)
df1

  Var WeightVar NewVar
   10      0.75    7.5
   20      0.80   16.0
   30      0.10    3.0
```

Comment: Thanks @neilfws - that solution makes complete sense. However, in this instance (as odd as it may seem) I don't want to vectorize my weights variable. As adamqueck pointed out, the get() function works perfectly in this scenario.

Comment: Sure. But in general, I think it's important that data structure should not dictate solutions. If you find yourself saying "I have to do it this way because that's how my data looks", that's generally an indication that you should do some work on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since many R operators (including `*`) are vectorised you can create one vector with variables and one vector with weights and then just multiply them:

```
vars <- c(1, 2, 3)
weights <- c(10, 20, 30)
vw <- vars * weights

# > vw
# [1] 10 40 90
```

Comment: Thanks @kristofferwitherballing - that solution makes complete sense. However, in this instance (as odd as it may seem) I don't want to vectorize my weights variable. As adamqueck pointed out, the get() function works perfectly in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, by adding get() wrapped around my paste command, it treats the variable as a value rather than a character block. Thanks to @AdamQuek for comment.

```
WeightVar1 <- .75
WeightVar2 <- .8
WeightVar3 <- .10

df<- data.frame(Var1 = 20
       ,Var2 = 30
       ,Var4 = 40)

for (i in 1:3)
{
df$Var_New <- df[i] * get(paste("WeightVar",i,sep=""))
names(df)[names(df) == "Var_New"] <- paste("Var",i,"_New",sep="")
}
```

This allows for a lot of flexibly when I don't know the number of variables/weights upfront.

Thanks!